# How do I set values in group of a FormBuilder control?

Tags: angular, typescript, formbuilder

**This is my control in FormBuilder:**

```
this.exampleForm.addControl("Date", this.formBuilder.group({
    'Month': [0],
    'Year': [0]
}));
```

I want to change the value of `Month/Year` in the control,

I know it's something like

```
let control = <FormControl>this.exampleForm.controls['Date'];
control.setValue(1);
```

But I belive it can be done something like

```
<FormArray>this.exampleForm.controls['Date'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let control = <FormArray>this.exampleForm.controls['Date'];
control.controls['Month'].setValue("0"); // setting value here
```

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html

Comment: Please edit your answer with explanation, or if you can't explain the code, please provide helpful link(s) (but it's not preferred since links can expire or content may change). You should avoid posting answers in fashion that satisfy the rules of "gimme code please" questions.